# A C code to reverse a string

Tags: c, string, debugging, reverse

Does anybody see the bug here? I have got alternate solutions.

```
int main()
{

  char line[100], res[100], temp[20];
  fgets( line, 100*sizeof(char), stdin);    
  int i, j, l;
  for( i=strlen(line)-1; i>=0; i--)
  {
    if(line[i]==' ')
        for(j=i+1, l=0; line[j]!=' ' && line[j]!='\0'; l++, j++)
            temp[l]=line[j];
    temp[++l]=' ';
    temp[++l]='\0';
    strcat(res, temp);
  }
  puts(res);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please tell us what behaviour you are actually seeing and how it differs from the expected behaviour.

Comment: Never do this `for( i=strlen(line)-1; i>=0; i--)`, you are computing the length of the string `length` of the string times, you should know that `strlen()` loops through the characters to count them.

Comment: `strcat(res, temp);` - that isn't good. You never setup `res[]` as a terminated buffer, and `strcat` expects it to be so. So the hunt is on to find a `0` char, and if you're (un)lucky, you find one with enough space left over to actually concatenate your source string.

Answer (score 0):

**l** and **j** are initialized just when **line[i]==' '**.

Witch won't be the case for the first iteration, where **line[i]** would be **'\n'**

Answer (score 0):

The `for` and `if` loop are not required. Since the array follows 0 based indexing, `i` should take values from `0` to `strlen(line)-1`, so `j=i+1` should be `j=i` (line 1). Strings should be null terminated - line 2. Also, `l` is already incremented in the `for loop`, so instead of pre-increment, use post-increment (or do not use it at all) (line 3).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{

 char line[100], res[100], temp[20];
 fgets( line, 100*sizeof(char), stdin);
 int i, j, l=0;
 res[0]='\0';   //line 2
 i=strlen(line)-1;

    for(j=i, l=0; line[j]!=' ' && line[j]!='\0'; l++, j--) //line 1
        {temp[l]=line[j];
         }
   temp[l++]=' ';   //line 3 (or temp[l]=' ')
   temp[l++]='\0';

   strcat(res, temp);

  puts(res);
  return 0;
}
```